# The way planets rotate and revolve

Tags: newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, solar-system

Why is that the all planets move in the same plane?(correct me if I'm wrong)

Why not some of them in anticlockwise direction and others in clockwise direction?

Comment: Uranus revolves in the opposite direction to that of the other planets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are our planets in the solar system all on the same disc/plane/layer?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26083/why-are-our-planets-in-the-solar-system-all-on-the-same-disc-plane-layer)

Comment: Also see: Can gravitational effects create a plane of the ecliptic?  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224800/can-gravitational-effects-create-a-plane-of-the-ecliptic/224872#224872

Answer (score 1):

Pluto's orbit is angled 17 degrees against the ecliptic and the other planets have slight inclination angles, too. Planets that form in the same planetary cloud and aren't disturbed too much during their evolution will inherit the original rotation of that cloud. There are, however, examples of exoplanets with retrograde orbits (i.e. the planet orbits in the other direction relative to the star's rotation), indicating that something (another star?) reversed their orbit or that they were captured after the system had already formed.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the planets revolve in the same direction because the planetary disc that formed the planets rotates in a direction